# error with extracting a list from a file

Tags: list, writer

In Python 2.7, I used this code to write a list of floats into a file:

```
with open(filename, "a") as file:
     writer = csv.writer(file)
     writer.writerow(GGDr_L)
```

and to get this list, I used

```
for numberString in line.split(","):
    number = np.float64(numberString)
    RL.append(number)
```

it works very well in python 2.7 but with python 3.6, i got an error related to the latest float in the list, I got

```
number = np.float64(numberString)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

when I tried to print this last float in the list, it was writed correctly, but with empty line after the float!! could this be the reason of the error??